# Android QR optical scanner - auto open browser if QR code contains URL

Tags: android, java.util.scanner, qr-code, barcode, barcode-scanner

I am new to this so please be gentile :P

I have purchase an optical barcode scanner which runs off of android.

So i doesnt scan using a camera. Currently when it scans a barcode or QR code it simply returns the product data.

What i really need it to do is if the QR code contains a URL, it auto opens it in the browser on the handset (which is basically like an android phone with chrome installed)

I only have access to a few settings on the handset but i think i have access to the android coding to allow me to tell it to carryout certain actions.

By default it is set to "keyboard output mode", so i changed this to the other option of "Intent output"

This has two settings i can change:

The first is titled "Intent action" and contains the action: android.intent.ACTION_DECODE_DATA

I can edit this field

The second is titled "Intent extra string" and contains the action: barcode_string

I can also edit this field

I wondered if i could change the code in one of these fields to tell the device to open a URL in the browser if a URL is found when scanned?

Thank you in advance for any input.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JolP.jpg)

I have tried adding all sorts of different code but am totally new to android and also not sure how the device is set up in the background.

I thought something like the below may be what i need but not sure how to input it into the devide

Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);i.setData(Uri.parse(url));startActivity(i);

Answer (score 0):

```
    String str = "https://www.google.com/";
  if(str.startsWith("https://")) {
     // Open browser 
     return;
  }
  
  if(str.startsWith("http://")) {
     // Open browser 
     return;
  }

 // contains not Url do something
```

Comment: While the question does need more clarification, they are asking about how to extract the data, not what about what they can do with the data once extracted.

Comment: Thanks for the response that is really helpful. In your opinion, do you think the device is already loaded with some of the code in the background? Leaving me only two boxes to edit, bein the "Intent action" & "Intent extra string". Would you suggest completely overwriting the code android.intent.ACTION_DECODE_DATA with your code above?